# Making a Symfony2 NullDateType form type that handles null values too

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm wondering how I could design a reusable custom form type, that consists of two radio buttons that tell whether a value is `NULL` or not, and one actual field containing the data when the non-NULL radio button is selected. This field can for example be `<input type="date">`.

So if the data value is NULL, the first radio button should be selected and the actual field should be disabled. If the value is non-NULL, the second radio button should be selected and the non-NULL value could for example represent a date (given a UNIX timestamp).

In HTML, it looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="radio" name="expiration_nullnonnull" value="_null" checked="checked" />
    </span>
    <span class="form-control">never</span>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="radio" name="expiration_nullnonnull" value="_nonnull" />
    </span>
    <input type="date" name="expiration" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

Now I've created a `NullType`, that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class NullType extends AbstractType {

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'null_value' => '_null',
            'null_label' => 'unknown',
            'nonnull_value' => '_nonnull',
            'nonnull_widget' => 'nonnull_widget',
        ]);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        $view->vars['null_value'] = $options['null_value'];
        $view->vars['null_label'] = $options['null_label'];
        $view->vars['null_checked'] = null === $form->getViewData();
        $view->vars['nonnull_value'] = $options['nonnull_value'];
        $view->vars['nonnull_widget'] = $options['nonnull_widget'];
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return FormType::class;
    }

}
```

And now, for each of the data types I want a nullable variant of, I create a specific type like this, `NullDateType` for example:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class NullDateType extends NullType {

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'nonnull_widget' => 'nonnull_date_widget',
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return NullType::class;
    }

}
```

My custom `fields.html.twig` looks like this:

```
{% block null_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
        <div class="input-group m-b-xs">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ null_value }}"{% if null_checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
            </span>
            <label class="form-control" for="{{ id }}">{{ null_label }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ nonnull_value }}"{% if not null_checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
            </span>
            {{ block(nonnull_widget) }}
        </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block nonnull_widget %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block nonnull_date_widget %}
    {% set widget = 'single_text' %}
    {% set type = 'date' %}
    {{ block('date_widget') }}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm having quite a few questions:

- Since I have two different variables (whether the value is null or
  not (i.e. the radio buttons), and the actual data field (i.e. the date field)), how do I handle it so they can act upon one form variable and also return it as one value?
- Am I using the right composition to support several nullable data types?